# Save photo in internal storage

Tags: android, camera, save, photo, internal

I have a problem that is i take a photo i want to save it in internal storage. but i don't know how do make it.Who can suggest some solution ? thanks.
There is my code:

```
public class ThreeFragment extends Fragment {


private static final String TAG = ThreeFragment.class.getSimpleName();
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
View root;
GridView gridView;
String mCurrentPhotoPath;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_three, container, false);
    dolist();
    return root;
}
public void dolist() {
    gridView = (GridView) root.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity()));
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    openGallery();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    takePhoto();
                    break;

                case 2:
                    Log.d(TAG, "333333333333333333333");
                    break;
                default:

                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}

private void takePhoto() {

    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}
private String saveToInternalSorage(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getActivity());
    File dic = cw.getDir("TEST", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    File mypath = new File(dic, ".jpg");
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dic.getAbsolutePath();
}

public void openGallery() {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
    else if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            saveToInternalSorage(bitmap);

           // setPath(saveToInternalSorage(bitmap));
        }

    }
}

}
```

Comment: what ever you are getting in onActivityResult in a thumbnail. Do you want to save the original image into storage ?

Comment: yes. im just save it. but after take a photo  my app appear error 
 Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=196609, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.qtv.myapplication/com.example.qtv.myapplication.view.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: uri

Comment: There is a simple way of doing it : mTempImageFile : It is path where you want to store your image file. Uri tempURI = Uri.fromFile(mTempImageFile);
                    Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, tempURI);
                    activity.startActivityForResult(i, CHOOSE_CAMERA_RESULT);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*Try This :
File mImageFile is path where you want to store you camera image file.

Uri tempURI = Uri.fromFile(mImageFile);
Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, tempURI);
activity.startActivityForResult(i, CHOOSE_CAMERA_RESULT);


then in your onActivityResult

@Override
public void onActivityResultRAW(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResultRAW(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode)
    {
    case CHOOSE_CAMERA_RESULT:
    {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            // here you image has been save to the path mImageFile.
            Log.d("ImagePath", "Image saved to path : " + mImageFile.getAbsoultePath());
        }
    }
    break;
    }
}*
```

Comment: sr .. maybe u understand wrong my ideal . i want save on path like the same "This PC\Nexus 5\Internal storage\DCIM\.thumbnails" . when we open it on PC , u can see all picture.

Comment: @AceAkatsuki you can store your image where ever you want to store, just give that path for example mImageFile = Envinorment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.Seperator + "DCIM" ; it will store the image in this location. Please explain me if I understood wrongly.

Comment: File mImageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "DCIM"); but log not show .
when i add  "DCIM\\.abc") (abc is floder is exits) then appear error Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.io.File.getAbsolutePath()' on a null object reference . can u explain me. thanks .

Comment: @AceAkatsuki can you please share your code for this. preferably github ghist

Comment: i try  many case, i hope u show me the bug. 
there is link github . my problem in ThreeFragment.class. 
https://github.com/QuangTo/DemoSimple/tree/qtv/app/src

Comment: Hi AceAkatsuki Please modify your mImageFile = mImageFile= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "DCIM" + File.separator + "temp.png"); and on ActivityResult Please re-name this temp.png file to what ever name you want. I hope this will work for you

Comment: ok i see. thank bro very much. u good. :D now i will  create folder in there and save it.

Comment: @AceAkatsuki : did this solution work for you ? if yes please accept this answer :) thanks.

Comment: hello dex. sr for don't answer ur question. i forgot it. i so sr. i did solution . thanks for support me. im save image and take it . :)) nice day bro. u good developer.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, setImageUri());
cameraIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
mActPanelFragment.startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, ActivityConstantUtils.CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

// method

```
 public Uri setImageUri() {

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), ActivityConstantUtils.STORED_IMAGE_PATH+"/Images/WOMCamera");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
    }
    ActivityConstantUtils.mCurrentPhotoPath = (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/"+"IMG_"+ System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
    Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(ActivityConstantUtils.mCurrentPhotoPath));
    if (file.canWrite()) {
    }
    return imgUri;
}
```

After that write code for result:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == ActivityConstantUtils.GALLERY_INTENT_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                String imagePath = getFilePath(data);
    }
    }

private String getFilePath(Intent data) {
        String imagePath;
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        imagePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        return imagePath;

    }
```

Comment: "ActivityConstantUtils.mCurrentPhotoPath " static variable you replace it with Global or Local Variable . DataType must be String.

Comment: Really i don't understand. pls explain it. im noob.  ActivityConstantUtils is class. cuz i see it call child method ..

Comment: Don't confuse Replace that complete variable with "String mImagePath".

Comment: thanks bro. i try your code but i don't see any change. i add Log.d below  String imagePath = getFilePath(data); to get imagePAth but nothing to show.. it not get path ?? . u can explain me ?

Comment: maybe my question is wrong. i want  to save photo like the link  "This PC\Nexus 5\Internal storage\DCIM\.abc" . in there folder  abc is exits. all photo in my app is save at there.